# Group the tables to a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have around 124 **tables** at a location which is to dumped into a database.
I have made an array which has name of all 124 tables,now how can I dump all these tables into database(under single name),using some for loop,Is this possible?

Or how I make all these SQL table files into a single SQL file so that it can be easily imported to database.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the safest way to import data is to do the following:

1. Import the 127 files into staging tables where all the columns are strings.
2. Create the final table with the columns and types that you want (along with other useful columns such as an auto-incremented id).
3. Insert the staging table data into the final table, one table at a time, finding and fixing errors as they arise.
4. Add indexes and triggers to the final table.
5. Delete or archive the staging tables.

This allows you to fix problems as they arise.  You can generate code for steps (1) and (3) using a spreadsheet or by using prepared statements in SQL.

Comment: U mean to say it requires a manual import of n number of tables? Is it

Comment: "manual" if you like.  You can generate the code and run it all at once.

Comment: can u provide some example?